# Declare an array in a shell script

Tags: sh

On the command line you can declare an array as

```
# a=()
```

but in inside a script

```
#!/bin/sh

a=()

echo "length is ${#a[@]}"
```

it doesn't work.

```
# sh ./array.sh
./array.sh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Is it possible to use arrays in scripts? How?

Comment: So the answer is: _no because `sh` does not have arrays_?

Comment: Exactly; use Bash or ksh (or Zsh) instead. Your interactive shell is probably Bash or some shell that *does* support arrays.

Comment: That is to say, use `./my-script-that-uses-arrays`, and start that script with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (`.sh` [extensions are a bad habit](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) that encourages people to use `sh` to run even scripts that _aren't_ really POSIX sh scripts, causing the problem seen here; don't perpetuate it).